# OpenCV: opencv_createsamples tool parse error

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

I tried many things to make the opencv_createsamples command work, no results. I try to create an OpenCV format training set using photos. I specify files names and rectangles coordinates in the descriptive info file and I always get this parse error. I simplified to one single example, still does not work. Num parameter is there. Windows 7 env.
My command:

```
C:\lib\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin>opencv_createsamples -info C:\opencv_ws\info.txt -bg C:\opencv_ws\bg.txt -num 1 -w 360 -h 640 -vec platesCl.vec
```

My info file:

```
pos/test_img01.jpg 1 10 10 24 24
```

I tried using "\", tabs, absolute path, two lines with all ending characters, smaller img dimensions and still stuck.
Maybe there is something I am missing, I don't know - still, seems in accordance with the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, actually, the opencv_createsamples.exe tool (Windows) does not like Windows End Of File character. I edited the info descriptor (positives samples) on Linux and fed it to the tool on Windows and it worked like a charm.